# Get ImageSource from Bitmap?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set a background image for my form/window [like this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009775/change-wpf-window-background-image-in-c-sharp-code) but instead of an image file on disk I've got a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in memory.

I need to do something like this:

```
this.Background = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(bmp));
```

Except `BitmapImage` won't take a `Bitmap`, nor will `ImageBrush` and I'm not sure if any of the others will. There's one called `BitmapCacheBrush` but I don't know what that does.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

```
public static Brush CreateBrushFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    return new ImageBrush(Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bmp.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()));
}
```

[credit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/87c45358-55ff-4869-a2d4-dafef84916de)

Comment: You'll need to import and P/Invoke DeleteObject on that handle from Bitmap.GetHBitmap() or you'll be leaking GDI handles. Refer to the documentation for more info.